# "RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 32 3 3, but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 224, 224] instead"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use a pre-trained model. Here's where the problem occurs

Isn't the model supposed to take in a simple colored image? Why is it expecting a 4-dimensional input?

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-d7abe3ef1355> in <module>()
     33 
     34 # Forward pass the data through the model
---> 35 output = model(data)
     36 init_pred = output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1] # get the index of the max log-probability
     37 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    336                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    337         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 338                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    339 
    340 

RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 32 3 3, but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 224, 224] instead
```

Where

```
inception = models.inception_v3()
model = inception.to(device)
```

Comment: A torch model normally expects a batch of images as input. If you want to pass a single image, make sure it is still a batch of single image. Also, Inception-v3 expects image dimensions to be 3X229X229 unlike other torch models which expect 3X224X224.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As [Usman Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237381/runtimeerror-expected-4-dimensional-input-for-4-dimensional-weight-32-3-3-but#comment100977502_57237381) wrote in his comment, pytorch (and most other DL toolboxes) expects a *batch* of images as an input. Thus you need to call

```py
output = model(data[None, ...])
```

Inserting a singleton "batch" dimension to your input `data`.

Please also note that the model you are using might expect a different input size (3x229x229) and not 3x224x224.

Comment: I also had to add `data[None, ...].float()` to make it work

Comment: @chavezbosquez you should look at `.to(...)` to move/cast your input tensor into the right data type/device as expected from your model.

Comment: The conversion `.to(device)` was needed as the input image was loaded using another mean (most likely with PIL from a WebDataSet). The value of `device`can be set as follows: `device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")`.

Answer (score 35):

From the Pytorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) on convolutional layers, `Conv2d` layers expect input with the shape

```
(n_samples, channels, height, width) # e.g., (1000, 1, 224, 224)
```

Passing grayscale images in their usual format (*224, 224*) won't work.

To get the right shape, you will need to add a channel dimension. You can do it as follows:

```
x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)      # if numpy array
tensor = tensor.unsqueeze(1)  # if torch tensor
```

The [`unsqueeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) method adds a dimensions at the specified index. The result would have shape:

```
(1000, 1, 224, 224)
```

Comment: For grayscale images, you are right. However, for an RGB image which needs to be seen as a batch of 1 image, that would be `.unsqueeze(0)`.

Comment: Can you explain **n_samples** here?

Comment: It's the number of training data, like the number of images

Answer (score 0):

As the model expects a batch of images, we need to pass a 4 dimensional tensor, which can be done as follows:

Method-1: `output = model(data[0:1])`
Method-2: `output = model(data[0].unsqueeze(0))`

This will only send the first image of the whole batch.

Similarly for ith image we can do:

Method-1: `output = model(data[i:i+1])`
Method-2: `output = model(data[i].unsqueeze(0))`