# Raw Image Python 4 Dimensions

Tags: python, image

A raw image in Python has four dimensions. 
For an Image I have a shape like that: 
5182 3444 1 7

I gues the first two dimensions are for height and width but what does the 1 and the 7 stand for? 
Can somoene explain, please?

Comment: Maybe tell us where you got it, what application produced it, what the file extension is...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using an ML framework such as *PyTorch*, because they load images with 4 dimensions. Those 4 dimensions from the outside in are:

- **n_samples / batch_size**: GPUs are efficient for processing many images in parallel, so you are expected so feed in a whole batch of say 32 distinct images.
- **n_channels**: Color (RGB) images have 3 values per pixel; *red, green, blue*; these are channels.
- **height**
- **width**

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59566009/2111778).