# RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight X, but got 3-dimensional input of size Y instead

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN to do image classification on the EMNIST dataset.

To do so, I have the following datasets:

```
import scipy .io
emnist = scipy.io.loadmat(DIRECTORY + '/emnist-letters.mat')
data = emnist ['dataset']
X_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,28,28), order='F')

y_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]

X_test = data ['test'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1,28,28), order = 'F')

y_test = data ['test'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]
```

With shape:

1. X_train = (124800, 28, 28)
2. y_train = (124800, 1)
3. X_test = (20800, 28, 28)
4. y_test = (20800, 1)

Note that the pictures are grayscale, so the colors are represented with only one number.

Which I prepare further as follows:

```
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train), torch.from_numpy(y_train))
test_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_test), torch.from_numpy(y_test))

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, 
                                           batch_size=batch_size, 
                                           shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, 
                                          batch_size=batch_size, 
                                          shuffle=False)
```

My model looks as follows:

```
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()

        self.cnn_layers = Sequential(
            # Defining a 2D convolution layer
            Conv2d(1, 4, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            BatchNorm2d(4),
            ReLU(inplace=True),
            MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            # Defining another 2D convolution layer
            Conv2d(4, 4, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            BatchNorm2d(4),
            ReLU(inplace=True),
            MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        )

        self.linear_layers = Sequential(
            Linear(4 * 7 * 7, 10)
        )

    # Defining the forward pass    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn_layers(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.linear_layers(x)
        return x

model = CNNModel()
```

The code below is part of the code that I use to train my model:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

    images = Variable(images)
    labels = Variable(labels)

    # Forward pass to get output/logits
    outputs = model(images)
```

However, by excuting my code, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [4, 1, 3, 3], but got 3-dimensional input of size [100, 28, 28] instead
```

So a 4D input is expected while my input is 3D. What can I do so a 3D model is expected rather than a 4D model?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237381/runtimeerror-expected-4-dimensional-input-for-4-dimensional-weight-32-3-3-but) a similar question is asked, however I dont see how I can translate this to my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convolution expects the input to have size *[batch_size, channels, height, width]*, but your images have size *[batch_size, height, width]*, the *channel* dimension is missing. Greyscale is represented with a single channel and you have correctly set the `in_channels` of the first convolutions to 1, but your images don't have the matching dimension.

You can easily add the singular dimension with [`torch.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze).

Also, please don't use [`Variable`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated), it was deprecated with PyTorch 0.4.0, which was released over 2 years ago, and all of its functionality has been merged into the tensors.

```py
for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
    # Add a single channel dimension
    # From: [batch_size, height, width]
    # To: [batch_size, 1, height, width]
    images = images.unsqueeze(1)

    # Forward pass to get output/logits
    outputs = model(images)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. What do you mean by the three lines of comments? Do you have example code how to do this?

Comment: The comments describe what the single line of code below them does.